# the delete affect the performance of my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

In my database through stored procedures I'm using deletes in certain tables , what I know is that if they delete affect future performance of my database , considering that use quite often.

I use SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices (might) get less good with every change.
Having the Delete (or Insert or Update) execute in a stored procedure does not change anything for good nor bad.